# Grunt Failed to send request to test.salesforce.com while installing ngForce

Tags: visualforce, force.com, sandbox, angularjs

I am pretty new to salesforce. Just trying to install the Angular ngForce into my developer edition of salesforce, I am getting the error as below

```
      "BUILD FAILED
    C:\salesforce.training\ngForce\node_modules\grunt-ant-sfdc\tmp\ant\build.xml:13:
     Failed to login: Failed to send request to https://test.salesforce.com/services
    /Soap/u/29.0

Total time: 23 seconds Use --force to continue.
"
```

I followed the steps as below :

1. Downloaded the zip file from https://github.com/noeticpenguin/ngForce
2. Ran "npm install"
3. Ran "npm install grunt-cli -g"
4. grunt deploy
5. Given my salesforce userID, password without security token and my security token

Got the above error as Build Failed.

In the Grunt JS, I modified "test.salesforce.com" to "login.salesforce.com", but the result is almost the same.